# Restart a package with a clean state

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could someone remind me a way to flush/reset our package. There are some files needed to be deleted inside a package, like "something to do with cache, the file name", and so on. I did this long time ago, but, now I forgot already.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27786/restart-a-package-with-a-clean-state/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand you correctly, a "make clean" when in the package directory should do it. To also rebuild dependencies you can also do a "rosmake [your_package_name] --pre-clean".

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4